# Number theory word problem and polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

> During a research trip $11$ men and $n$ women are gathering exotic mushrooms. All together they collect $n^2+9n-2$ mushrooms and everyone collects the same amount of mushrooms. Determine if there were more women or men at the trip.

This was asked on a number theory problem set, but for me it doesn't seem like a number theory problem. My initial thought was to see if I could find anything by dividing $n^2+9n-2$, but didn't get anywhere. What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Since

$$
n^2+9n-2=(n+11)(n-2)+20,
$$
if $n+11$ divides $n^2+9n-2$, then $n+11$ divides $20$.

Also observe that if $n>11$ then $n+11>22$ cannot divide $20$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the only possible divisor that we can then get is $n=9$?

Comment: NP. Yes, I think that is the case, though the problem does not ask for that information. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The number of mushrooms collected by each person is $\frac{n^2 + 9n - 2}{n + 11}$. This is equivalent to $\frac{n^2 + 11n - 2n - 2}{n+11} = \frac{n(n+11) - 2(n+11) + 20}{n+11} = n - 2 + \frac{20}{n+11}$, which you can also show by polynomial long division or synthetic division.

This number must be a whole number. Which value(s) of $n$ make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

well if you let the mushrooms collected by each member to be '$m$' then we have to find '$n$' such that  $\frac{n^2 + 9n - 2}{n+11} \in \mathbb{N}$. well so we should have, $ \,(n+11) | (n^2 +9n -2) \,$ ,  $ n^2 + 9n - 2 = (n+11)(n-2) + 20 $

Comment: Did you not see awllower's answer when you were writing your answer? I don't see the difference between your answer and awllower's answer.

Comment: i just saw and started answering there was no answer back then, i'll delete the post if you wish i have no problems

Comment: I see; in that case you don't have to delete your answer.

Comment: well i guess that's okay